# question on integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Let $\displaystyle A=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^8}$. Then which of the following are true:

1) $A\lt 1$,

2) $A\gt 1$,

3) $A\lt \frac{\pi}{4}$,

4) $A\gt\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Actually one can prove by psychology that that the answer is (1) and (4), because otherwise in any other case one inequality would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

If $0\lt x\lt 1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}\lt \frac{1}{1+x^8}\lt \frac{1}{1+0^2}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\lt\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^8}dx\lt\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+0^2}dx=1.$$

That leads that the answer $4)$ and $1)$.

Comment: thanksyou  very much sir .

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Hint. $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$